# Missing tabs on Emacs

Tags: tabs

I have been using Emacs for one week, so all of it is really new for me.

I saw that there are two types of commands in order to navigate in emacs :
- Some "tabs" on the top
- Commands like shortcuts

Nevertheless, my tabs are missing.
Do you have a clue how to activate them ?

Comment: Do you mean the tool bar? If yes, you can try typing M-x (or alt x) tool-bar-mode

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. What do you mean by "tab" here? Can you describe what you're looking for? Do you see the same behavior, or do you see the behavior you want, if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)?

Answer (score 1):

Tab functionality ala your web browser is provided by an external package `tabbar-mode`. The source code is on [github](https://github.com/dholm/tabbar), and there is an extensive page about customizing it on the [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TabBarMode). In fact the first Google Search hit for "emacs tabs" points to the EmacsWiki page. It's also available as a package via [Melpa](https://melpa.org/#/tabbar).

Once installed you can toggle it on or off with `M-x tabbar-mode`. To turn it on at startup you can put the following in your init file.

```lisp
(require 'tabbar)
(tabbar-mode 1)
```

If you're using Aquamacs, it's enabled by default and you can disable it at startup by putting the following in your init file.

```lisp
(when (featurep 'aquamacs)
  (tabbar-mode -1))
```

Comment: Also: [awesome-tab](https://github.com/manateelazycat/awesome-tab) and [centaur-tabs](https://github.com/ema2159/centaur-tabs).

Comment: With respect to the claim that `tabbar-mode` originated with Aquamacs, it would be interesting to see some documentation linking David Ponce (the original author of `tabbar.el`) with the Aquamacs project as it relates to that library.

Comment: Meh, I was wrong. At least I wasn't snarky about it.